# Represent hand shape in time series curve in Visual c++ using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

I have to represent hand as a cluster of finger segments in time series curve.( *Horizontal axis* - Angle between one fixed point to each contour vertex. 
*vertical axis* - Euclidean distance between center point(in hand) and each contour vertex ) .Is there is any algorithm for drawing that curve?
How can I represent the hand shape in time series curve?

Thanks in advance.